# File searching in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, dir

I wrote a vba code that browse all path folder and search for "strings.xml" file.

```
Dim oFS As Office.FileSearch
Dim i As Integer
Set oFS = Application.FileSearch

With oFS
    .NewSearch
    .FileType = msoFileTypeAllFiles
    .Filename = "strings.xml"
    .LookIn = "D:\Workspace"
    .SearchSubFolders = True
    .Execute

    MsgBox "Finish ! " & .FoundFiles.Count & " item found !"
End With
```

However, in my workspace I have many "strings.xml" files that this current code locates and but I only want to find the "strings.xml" within a specific subfolder; e.g. `./values/strings.xml`  files.

Comment: do you know that fron Office 2007 the Office.FileSearch won't be available?

Answer (score 1):

The following will look recursively under your root working folder for `Values\Strings.xml` matches and list them in a [Scripting.Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251825.aspx) object.

The main file/folder search is performed by the simple [Dir function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278779.aspx).

```
Sub dir_ValuesStringsXML_list()
    Dim f As Long, ff As String, fp As String, fn As String, tmp As String
    Dim vfn As Variant, dFILEs As Object    'New scripting_dictionary

    Set dFILEs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dFILEs.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

    'set vars for c:\temp\Workspace\*\Values\Strings.xml
    fp = Environ("TMP") & Chr(92) & "Workspace"
    ff = "Values"
    fn = "Strings.xml"
    dFILEs.Item(fp) = 0

    'get folder list
    Do
        f = dFILEs.Count
        For Each vfn In dFILEs
            If Not CBool(dFILEs.Item(vfn)) Then

                tmp = Dir(vfn & Chr(92) & Chr(42), vbDirectory)
                Do While CBool(Len(tmp))
                    If Not CBool(InStr(1, tmp, Chr(46))) Then
                        dFILEs.Item(vfn & Chr(92) & tmp) = 0
                    End If
                    tmp = Dir
                Loop
                'Debug.Print dFILEs.Count
                dFILEs.Item(vfn) = 1
            End If
        Next vfn
    Loop Until f = dFILEs.Count

    'remove the folders and check for Values\Strings.xml
    For Each vfn In dFILEs
        If CBool(dFILEs.Item(vfn)) Then
            If LCase(Split(vfn, Chr(92))(UBound(Split(vfn, Chr(92))))) = LCase(ff) And _
               CBool(Len(Dir(vfn & Chr(92) & fn, vbReadOnly + vbHidden + vbSystem))) Then
                dFILEs.Item(vfn & Chr(92) & fn) = 0
            End If
            dFILEs.Remove vfn
        End If
    Next vfn

    'list the files
    For Each vfn In dFILEs
        Debug.Print "from dict: " & vfn
    Next vfn

    dFILEs.RemoveAll: Set dFILEs = Nothing

End Sub
```

---

<sub>If you wish to convert the late binding of the Scripting.Dictionary to early binding, you must add **[Microsoft Scripting Runtime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hww8txat.aspx)** to the VBE's Tools ► References.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I think you are saying that you want to look in the sub-folder "\values" for files called **strings.xms**

If that's right, try the below amended code:

```
Dim oFS As Office.FileSearch
Dim i As Integer
Set oFS = Application.FileSearch

With oFS
    .NewSearch
    .FileType = msoFileTypeAllFiles
    .Filename = "strings.xml"
    .LookIn = "D:\Workspace\values"
    .SearchSubFolders = True
    .Execute

    MsgBox "Finish ! " & .FoundFiles.Count & " item found !"
End With
```

of course, you may not want to specify the sub-folder.

Here is another option:

```
Dim sPath As String 
Dim sFil As String 
Dim strName As String 

sPath = "D:\Workspace\values" 'Change Path
sFil = Dir(sPath & "string.xml") 'All files in Directory matching name

Do While sFil <> "" 
    strName = sPath & sFil 
    sFil = Dir 
     'Your Code Here.
    i=i+1
Loop 

MsgBox "Finish ! " & .FoundFiles.Count & " item found !"
```

Have you considered using the FileSystemObject to do a recursive search in a sub-folder only?

[MSDN - How to do a recursive search using the FileSystemObject](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/185601)

HTH

Philip

Comment: Well I 'am looking for every "strings.xml" file contained in every "values" folder. I shouldn't do .LookIn = "D:\Workspace\values" because it gives only "D:\Workspace\values\strings.xml" file, but I want also "D:\Workspace\....\values\strings.xml" files

Comment: so you need to do a recursive search by the sound of it... look at [HOW TO: Recursively Search Directories by Using FileSystemObject](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/185601)

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
sPath = "D:\Workspace\values" 'Change Path
sFil = Dir(sPath & "string.xml") 'All files in Directory matching name
```

with:

```
sPath = "D:\Workspace\values\" 'Change Path
sFil = Dir(sPath & "*.xl*") 'All files in Directory matching name
```