# VBA to look for a folder containing a certain string, open folder and copy a workbook to another location

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to Use VBA to create a compiler. It will take user input of a string and look for folders, within a folder, containing that string, enter the folder and copy the .xl* file from in there to a folder that I create.

```
     Sub outputsCompiler()

 Call GetFolder

 If Cells(1, 1) = 0 Then

 Exit Sub

 End If

 Call compileoutputsPrompt

 If Cells(1, 2) = 0 Then

 Exit Sub

 End If

 Dim i As Integer
' Dim ResultsFile
'
'    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

 For i = 2 To 9

     If (Cells(1, i) <> Empty) Then
'
'        ResultsFile = Dir(Cells(1, 1) & "*" & Cells(1, i) & "*.xl*")
'        Cells(3, 5) = ResultsFile

        MkDir (Cells(1, 1) & "CompiledOutputs" & Cells(1, i))

    '    DestFolder = Cells(1, 1) & "CompiledOutputs" & Cells(1, i)

              'FSO.CopyFile Source:=ResultsFile Destination:=DestFolder
    End If
  Next i

 End Sub
```

Everything in this code works, except the things I have commented out.  Also all of the Subs I call work fine. The strings I am searching for will be pasted in Row 1 Columns 2-9 and The folder containing all other folders, including the folder I will create is in Cells(1,1).

Comment: See [File searching in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15339006/file-searching-in-vba/35239732#35239732).

Comment: Seems as though this is useful, however I cannot actually figure out how to copy the file from the sub folder into my created folder, using just "*"Cells(1,i)"*.xl*"