# Copy files containing keyword from a subfolder, to a new folder containing same keyword

Tags: vba, excel

So I have been working on a code for a while, but I'm stuck on something. Basically my code calls "GetFolder" which takes the directory I want and puts that string in 1,1, then calls "compileDSoutputsPrompt" which prompts the user to input up to 9 numbers (could be any number but for now I'll say 100, 450, 900) and pastes them in Row 1, column i, starting at column 2.

^ This is all fine. I then use DSoutputsCompiler, to take these user inputs, and create corresponding folders in the same directory as Cells(1,1). Good, this works too.

Now I want to find excel files, containing these user inputted "keywords"/"keynumbers", if you will, within subfolders of my Cells(1,1) directory, and copy them to the newly created corresponding folders containing the same "keyword"/"keynumber".

I have viewed [File searching in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15339006/file-searching-in-vba/35239732#35239732) however, it didn't quite work for me, because I couldn't get the file actually copied.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, please see code below!

Thanks for your time!

```
Sub DSoutputsCompiler()


Dim sPath As String
Dim sFil As String
Dim strName As String


 Call GetFolder

 If Cells(1, 1) = 0 Then

 Exit Sub

 End If

 Call compileDSoutputsPrompt

 If Cells(1, 2) = 0 Then

 Exit Sub

 End If

 Dim j As Integer
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim ResultsFile

   Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

 For i = 2 To 9

     If (Cells(1, i) <> Empty) Then


          MkDir (Cells(1, 1) & "CompiledDSOutputs" & Cells(1, i))


sPath = Cells(1, 1)
sFil = Dir(sPath & "*" & Cells(1, i) & "*.xl*")

Do While sFil <> ""
    strName = sPath & sFil
    sFil = Dir

'So I guess here is where I would copy the file and paste it to the newly created folder

    j = j + 1
Loop

    End If
  Next i

 End Sub
```

Edit: I also need the exact file name in the new folder. I have replaced this:

```
Do While sFil <> ""
    strName = sPath & sFil
    sFil = Dir

    j = j + 1
Loop
```

With this:

```
SourceFile = Cells(1, 1) & "*" & Cells(1, i) & "*.xl*"

Filename = Replace(SourceFile, Cells(1, 1), "")

DestinationFile = Cells(1, 1) & "CompiledDSOutputs" & Cells(1, i) & "\" & Filename
FileCopy(SourceFile, DestinationFile)
```

I ran it 2 times, and got 2 different errors, one was Bad filename, the other was Path/File access error.

Can anybody tell me where I'm going wrong, and/or point me in the right direction?

Thanks again

Comment: FileCopy : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264390.aspx

Comment: How can I use this for multiple files, all in different subfolders, containing the same keyword, within my code?

Comment: I also want to copy the exact filename into the newly created folder, for identification purposes