# VBA Excel - Hyperlinks

Tags: excel, vba

I like to know if the address parameter (when you want to use Hyperlink in VBA) can be dynamic like If I saved a copy of my active sheet in X folder, can VBA copy that address not mather the place I choose for saving my document?

Thanks!

Comment: Would help to show an example of the type of link you're creating.

Comment: If you are "saving file as" then you can easly find [path of saved file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813925/how-to-get-the-path-of-current-worksheet-in-vba). If you want VBA to find specific file that you sometimes save on desktop sometimes somewhere else it will be hard to do but you can look for [file in subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15339006/file-searching-in-vba).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.